# is it possible to declare two application in AndroidManifest

Tags: android

the manifest is like this:

```
<manifest
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication1" >
        <MainActivity
        ...
    </application>

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication2" >
        <MyService
            android:process=":remote" />
    </application>
```

actually, i want to fix a issue like this:

if I declare service MyService, which runs in a private process, whthin MyApplication1, then two instances of MyApplication1 will be created, which means the initialization in MyApplication1 will be done twice.

So, i wanna to init a separate application when MyService is to be launched by declaring MyService in a separate application MyApplication2 as shown above in the manifest.
But unfortunately, it doesn't work as i think: MyService can not start at all.
have i omitted something, or made a fundamental mistake to try doing so?

Comment: go through basic of android

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible as mentioned on google guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filec

Comment: ok, thanks. what's weird is there is no compile error when i declare 2 application in manifest, so i got this misconception.

Answer (score 0):

Your app should have two processes if the Service runs in a remote process.

I guess that why you're seeing two "instances". But your activities and services will not be duplicated on those two instances.

Comment: yes, my components are not duplicated.  but i do a lot work in application.onCreate, and i don't want to do these work thice:(

Comment: What do you do?
Can't you move this work in your MainActivity.onCreate()?